# empty deque vs vector

Tags: c++, stl

I came across the following in a sample of STL quiz questions

Q: What will happen when you attempt to compile and run the following code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

void printer(int i) {
    cout << i << ", ";
}

int add (int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}

int main() {

    vector<int> v1 = { 3, 9, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5 };
    set<int> s1(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    deque<int> d1;      // LINE I
    transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), v1.begin(), d1.begin(), add);//LINE II
    for_each(d1.begin(), d1.end(), printer); //LINE III

    return 0;
}


A compilation error in LINE III
B program outputs: 3, 10, 2, 5, 5, 9, 14,
C program outputs: 3, 9, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 
D runtime error at LINE III 
E compilation error in LINE II 
F runtime error at LINE II 
G program outputs: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9,
```

From reading the code I expected the answer to be F, either because 
1   copying into a zero size container is undefined behaviour
or 2 the stl function might check at runtime that there is enough capacity and if not throw an exception

I compiled and ran the code on gcc  4.8.1

There were no compile or runtime errors. LINE III simply prints nothing because I assume d1.begin() == d1.end(). There are no valid elements in deque.

However if I add LINE IV

```
for_each(d1.begin(), d1.begin()+7, printer); //LINE IV
```

it prints

```
3, 10, 2, 5, 5, 9, 14,
```

so the transform function did write the 7 elements to "unmanaged" memory.

When I change LINE I to

```
vector<int> d1;
```

then a runtime error does occur on LINE II.

QUESTIONS

1   Can it be said that the question above does not supply an option for the correct answer. I'm not sure how other compilers would behave.

2   I'm assuming because deques do not necessarily use contiguous storage that there is some form of allocation happening thru the deque iterator when the transform function is writing elements to it. However the deque itself still has size of 0. But the vector iterator causes a crash when attempting to write to memory. Does anyone have a detailed explanation.

3   When writing utility functions of my own that may accept iterators, without knowing anything about the underlying container, what is the best way to handle this situation, where iterators to an inadvertantly empty container are passed. I think begin() == end() is guaranteed to be true for all empty containers, so perform this check initially and throw exception?

thanks

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: Down voters please comment

Comment: Your assumption 1 is correct, since the program has "undefined behaviour", any of the given answers are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to question 3:

You can use something like this to verify that the destination container is not only not empty, but is also of sufficient size:

```
if(std::distance(d1.begin(), d1.end()) < std::distance(s1.begin(), s1.end()))
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Not enough space");
}
```

Your assumption in question 1 seems to be correct. Both gcc and clang compile without errors.

Sorry I don't have detailed explanation for 2, but as you said this is undefined behaviour. The above example runs fine with `deque` when compiled with libstdc++ (both clang and gcc) , but segfaults with both `deque` and `vector` when compiled with libc++ and clang. So it seems the implementation of `deque` in libstdc++ always preallocates some space (even after running `d1.shrink_to_fit()`).